# Como criar um método estático usando Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, métodos-estáticos

No JAVA quando queremos criar um método estático, usamos `static`. Vejam:

```
public static String getDragonGlass(){
    return String.valueOf("All the dragon glasses.");
}
```

E no *Kotlin*, qual melhor forma de representar um método estático?

Comment: Relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352684/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-kotlin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin possui um mecanismo um pouco diferente. Dentro de uma classe:

```
companion object {
    fun getDragonGlass() : String = String.valueOf("All the dragon glasses.")
}
```

Chamaria como no Java:

```
Classe.getDragonGlass()
```

Existem variantes dessa sintaxe.

Há quem considere essa sintaxe verbosa demais, outros defendem que isso passa o conceito melhor e que ajuda evitar o abuso desse tipo de método.

[Documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).

Kotlin possui funções que não são métodos, então sequer precisa estar dentro de uma classe. Porém dentro de uma classe para diferenciar um método de uma função é preciso incluir em um objeto complementar.

Se quiser fazer fora da classe:

```
fun getDragonGlass() : String = String.valueOf("All the dragon glasses.")
```

Tem que estar dentro de um pacote. Assim a chamada será no contexto do pacote. Algo assim:

```
Pacote.getDragonGlass()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/StaticMethod.kt).

Comment: O `fun` seria o `static`? Ou o `companion` seria o `static`? Ou não tem nada a ver?

Comment: Não, o `fun` é palavra chave usada em todas as funções, mesmo os métodos normais usam. Isto é necessário porque o tipo do retorno vem depois da função, que é o local correto. Vou complementar a resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Não existem métodos estáticos em Kotlin.

É possível criar funções no nível do pacote/*package* porque, em Kotlin, não é necessário ter uma classe pra ter uma função definida.

Algo como

```
package acklay.pkg

fun getDragonGlass() = "All the dragon glasses";
```

Se for realmente necessário escrever uma função no nível da classe que não necessite de uma instância, mas, por exemplo, necessite de acesso aos membros internos da classe quaisquer que sejam (um método de *factory* é um bom exemplo). É possível criar a função como parte de uma "[declaração de objeto](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)" dentro da própria classe.

Por exemplo:

```
class Classe {
    private fun foo() = object {
        val dragonGlass: String = "All the dragon glasses"
    }

    fun bar() {
        val x = foo().dragonGlass
    }
}
```

Uma forma mais parecida com estáticos, são os [*companion objects*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

```
class JonSnow {
    companion object {
        fun getDragonGlass(): String = "All the dragon glasses."
    }
}
```

O uso seria assim

```
JonSnow.getDragonGlass()
```

[Veja funcionando no try.kotlin.](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/lbnrppvrfd0f413hmmbbjmdla/74kr84b9l0h6p7jkbsfeafvpbo)

Answer (score 0):

de acordo com o conversor de `java` para `kotlin`, o código correspondente seria:

```
fun getDragonGlass():String {
    return ("All the dragon glasses.").toString()
}
```

A declaração de tipo de retorno é feita após a declaração da função:

```
fun getDragonGlass():String ...
```

Para ver a conversão acesso [o conversor](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt) no canso superior direito.